# Homotopical interpretation of Langlands correspondence

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homotopy-theory, langlands-conjectures, ring-spectra

Recently I began learning about homotopy theory, I am very far from being familiar with all the basic notions and constructions, however I heard of the notion of topological modular forms. I also heard (very vaguely) that there is a notion of spectral algebraic geometry, and imagine there may also be a notion of a spectral abelian variety, and perhaps a spectral elliptic curve.

In case any of this makes sense, it may be reasonable to wonder if there is a meaningful incarnation of Langlands correspondence in homotopy theory. Can anyone in the know share some interesting insights?